# Как сделать так, чтобы TEREDO игнорировал подключенный VPN?

Tags: windows, сеть, vpn, windows-10, ipv6

Нужно чтобы Teredo обходил VPN стороной не присваивая его IP в локальное сопоставление. Как можно реализовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос. Нужно было прописать маршрут от сетевого интерфейса до сервера тередо.

Comment: А вы можете подсказать, как именно вы это сделали?